# Running a nested If/Match

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, nested, vlookup

I have 4 columns of data. They are two separate columns of First Name/Last Name columns copied and pasted together.

What I want to do is run a match on the last names and IF they are equal, run a match on the first names.

The column ranges are dynamic which is why running a CONCATENATE and VLOOKUP formula works, but if I can get something less involved it'd be great.

```
   A       B        C      D      E
1 Last  First   Last2   First2
2 Sharma  Abhi  Smith   Kevin
3 Philip  Matt  Smith   GEORGIA
4 Franc   Pete  John    Bon Jovi 
5 Arnold  Susan Jack    White
6 Mallo   Chad  Sharma  Katie
7 Daigle  Steve Sharma  Abhi
```

My thought is that starting in cell E2 it should return a match or not a match (in this case only Row 2 should return a match. Currently it's returning a match every time - which is definitely not right.

This is the code I've written so far

```
Sub matchFunction()

On Error Resume Next

Dim BW_Row As Long
Dim BW_Clm As Long
    Table1 = Sheet2.Range("F11:F16") ' Range of all appointments last name
    Table2 = Sheet2.Range("$G$11:$G$16") ' Range of all appointments first name
    Table3 = Sheet2.Range("$H$11:$H$16") ' Range of leads
    BW_Row = Sheet2.Range("J11").Row ' Change E column if it's a match
    BW_Clm = Sheet2.Range("J11").Column
    
        For Each c In Table1
            
            For Each d In Table2
                    
                If Application.Match(c, Table3, 0) <> "" Then
                    
                    If Application.Match(d, Table3, 0) <> "" Then
                    
                            Sheet2.Cells(BW_Row, BW_Clm) = "It's a Match!"
                    
                        Else
                                
                            Sheet2.Cells(BW_Row, BW_Clm) = "Sorry, it's not a match"
                            
                    
                    End If
                    
                End If
                    
        
        BW_Row = BW_Row + 1
        
        Next d
        
    Next c
                  
 MsgBox "Matching Finished"

End Sub
```

Comment: `running a CONCATENATE and VLOOKUP formula works, but if I can get something less involved` And then you are instead using complete over kill VBA that will run slower and be much more likely to fail?? Don't fix it if it isn't broke. Regardless, I don't see any matches in Column A in Column C, yet you say row 2 is match? IF row 2 is a match to row 3, why isn't rows 6 and 7 a match?

Comment: Definitely agree - I don't know too much about speed and VBA so if it's going to take me the same amount of time to do Concatenate and Vlookup then it might not be worth figuring this out. Row 2 (Columns A,B) matches to Row 7 (Columns C,D)

Answer (score 1):

+1 for @user2140261's comment... the VBA is going to be slower than your formula. However, if you're set on using VBA, insert this instead of your `For Each C` loop:

```
i = 11
For Each c In Table1
    If c = Cells(i, 8) Then
        If Cells(i, 7) = Cells(i, 9) Then sheet2.Cells(i, BW_Clm) = "It's a Match!"
    End If
    sheet2.Cells(i, BW_Clm) = "Sorry, it's not a match"
    i = i + 1
Next c
```

**Tested**

This will check `F11` against `H11`. If it's a match, it checks `G11` against `I11`, if that returns a match, `"It's a match!"` is written to `J11`. If it isn't a match, `"Sorry, it's not a match"` is written to `J11`. It then begins the loop over for row 12.

Answer (score 1):

Using VBA seems unnecessary for this. You could just throw in this array formula in E2 (hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

`=CHOOSE(MAX(IF(($C$2:$C$7=$A2)*($D$2:$D$7=$B2),2,1)),"Sorry, it's not a match","It's a Match!")`

The IF function assigns value 2 if both conditions are TRUE and value 1 if FALSE. MAX will find the highest value out of the array of values. CHOOSE will return the phrase based on the value. 1 = "no match", 2 = "match".

Comment: Yup this did it. This was super helpful - I looked up the Choose and Max operations to help me figure out what exactly this is doing. Thanks!